# Basic web scraping in Python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I need your help with web scraping using Python. I want to scrape this site below in order to get some information for 365 days ago from today. But I am unable to change the URL properly. I only get the first day. This is my first project and I am stuck.

The URL I have:
https://crossfit.com/workout/2017/11/04

The URL I am trying to get:
https://crossfit.com/workout/2017/11/03

And so on.

Here is my actual code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from time import sleep
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

base_url = 'https://www.crossfit.com/workout/'
count = 365
scrape_date = date.today()
sleep(2)
bs_obj = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
boxes = bs_obj.find_all('div',{'class':'wod active'})

for i in range(count):
    url = base_url + scrape_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    for box in boxes:
            dia = box.find('h1').text
            wod = box.find('p').text
    scrape_date -= timedelta(days=1)

print(dia, wod)
```

Comment: I created a list with for loop. But I cannot got join this list with the base URL in order to change with a new loop increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to scrape this site involves `datetime` math. If you need more resources, [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20working%20with%20datetime&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS766US766&oq=python%20working%20with%20datetime&aqs=chrome..69i57.11066j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) are your friends.

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

URL_BASE = "https://www./crossfit.com/workout/"
count = 365
scrape_date = date.today()
for i in range(count):
    url = URL_BASE + scrape_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

    # Do your scraping here....

    scrape_date -= timedelta(days=1)
    count -= 1
```

Comment: I tried your instructions but I got only the first date.

Comment: Try it again now

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the BeautifulSoup python library. You must install the module on your computer, but it is probably the most widely used and most user-friendly web scraping library.

Additionally it has a large amount of documentation as well, and plenty of examples since so many people use it.

Hope it helps. good luck.